# Exact solution for (simple) Reheating Boltzmann equations?

Tags: cosmology, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

Let's say we have the Universe which is exiting Inflation, with the inflaton field $\phi$ decaying into relativistic particles (radiation $R$).
Without any other assumption, the equations describing this cosmological background are the two Boltzmann equations for the energy densities and the first Friedmann equation:

$$\dot{\rho_\phi}+3H\rho_\phi= -\Gamma_\phi\rho_\phi,$$

$$\dot{\rho_R}+4H\rho_R=\phantom -\Gamma_\phi\rho_\phi,$$

$$H^2=\dfrac{1}{3M_P^2}(\rho_\phi+\rho_R).$$

where I used the reduced Planck mass $M_P=(8\pi G)^{-1/2}$ and $\Gamma_\phi$ is the decay rate of $\phi$.
Here, the dot stands for time-derivative.

How do you **exactly** solve them?

I know there are plenty of approximated solutions, such as in Kolb & Turner book, but I would like to find a way to get the exact one, from which I can derive a precise time-temperature relation, valid throughout this epoch.

In fact, one can hope to find a solution for the energy densities as a function of $t$ and, by exploiting the definition of temperature via the radiation bath, also the time-temperature relation, namely

$$T(t)=\left(\dfrac{30\rho_R(t)}{\pi^2g_*(tT(t))}\right)^{1/4}$$

where the number of relativistic degrees of freedom is almost frozen to $\approx 10^2$. I don't know how to do the proper calculation without any further hypothesis.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would assume that if Kolb and Turner discuss approximate solutions, this is because the equations have no exact analytic solution. There is no reason to assume that a differential equation, or a set of them, has a nice analytic solution.

Comment: I think this too... do you have any idea how to numerically solve this equation system?

Comment: I use the NDSolve[] function in Mathematica.